# post checkbox data using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

i have some html snip like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red"/>red
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="green"/>green
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="purple"/>purple
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="grey"/>grey
```

and i want to use jquery to post value to server, so i used jquery like this

```
$.post('/test', {'color': ['red', 'green']});
```

i did search this question in stackoverflow, but people say it's should be 'color[]' instead of 'color', but whenever i used 'color' or 'color[]' firebug displayed the post data is 'color%5B%5D=red&color%5B%5D=green', and my server can't work right, but when using

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

to post firebug says the data is 'color=red&color=green', and my server work right.
How could it be? my jquery version is 1.4.4

Comment: have you tried with **jQuery.ajax()** ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the jQuery developers decided that PHP's bizarre handling of multiple controls with the same name is The Correct Way. As a consequence, when submitting an array of data, jQuery will append `[]` to the name (`%5B%5D` is just a URL encoded representation of `[]`).

> to post firebug says the data is 'color=red&color=green', and my server work right

That suggests that you are using something other than PHP to process the data so PHP's magic handling of `[]` in names does not apply.

You can either look for `color[]` on the server…

e.g.

```
@values = $query->param('color[]');
```

… or you can set [traditional](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) mode to stop jQuery PHPifying your data.

```
$.post('/test', {'color': ['red', 'green']}, { traditional: true });
```

Then normal access should work:

```
@values = $query->param('color');
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I'd never really understood why jQuery was flattening the array in the way that it does. It all makes sense now!

Comment: Ok, that's right, and i used php to test again, it really works! BTW, I'm using web.py as my server...maybe i should learned some php right now, LOL

Answer (score 2):

I believe that when you call -

```
$.post('/test', {'color': ['red', 'green']});
```

an array is being passed as the post data and the flattening of the array is what's causing the 'color%5B%5D=red&color%5B%5D=green' result.

If you use the following -

```
$('input:checkbox[name="color"][checked=true]').serialize()
```

This should return all of the checked checkboxes in the 'color=red&color=green' format. 
There's a jsfiddle that attempts to illustrate the concept here - http://jsfiddle.net/789nP/.